# Scrolling увеличение картинки(android)

Tags: java, android, xml, swipe

Помогите придумать как сделать так: Имеется список чего то, к примеру новостей и вверху этого списка есть картинка, которая если я сделаю свайп вниз то она увеличится и загрузится новая порция новостей. Подскажите как сделать само увеличение при свайпе вниз, не могу ничего придумать. На картинках то что мне примерно нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**

Спасибо [pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff) за ссылку. Но у меня не получается сделать `SwipeRefreshLayout` вместе с `StretchLayout`. Пробовал много рас, но ошибка. Вот мой xml

```
<menuobject.StretchLayout
                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:orientation="vertical">

                                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                  android:id="@+id/swipe"
                                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                  android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/menuImageI"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                       android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                      <RelativeLayout
                          android:id="@+id/front_view"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:background="#f1f1f1"
                          android:orientation="vertical" >

                         <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listCategoryMenu"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                             />


                      </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



            </menuobject.StretchLayout>
```

В классе `StretchLayout` изменил строки:

```
  mStretchView = getChildAt(0);
        mFrontView = getChildAt(1);
```

на

```
mStretchView = getChildAt(1);
    mFrontView = getChildAt(2);
```

И ошибки:

```
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at menuobject.StretchLayout.onLayout(StretchLayout.java:68)
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11315)
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4314)
06-09 23:33:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1633)
```

68 строка:

```
mMargin = mStretchView.getMeasuredHeight()*mRatio;
```

Comment: Вам нужна следующая логика: картинка, внизу список. Когда список доходит до верха, картинка растягивается и обновляется содержимое списка? Тогда, к сожалению, `StretchLayout` не подойдет.Я изменил ответ, снимите отметку, что он правильный, если такой вариант вам не подходит.

Comment: @pavlofff я понял, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как для коректной работы виджета `SwipeRefreshLayout` вложенными в него могут быть только три типа элементов: `ScrollView`,`ListView`,`GridView` , я предлагаю использовать внешнюю библиотеку [`ObservableScrollView`](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView), виджеты которой как раз наследуются от трех перечисленных элементов. Это должно работать правильно.
В противном случае надо будет реализовать кастомный компонент для реализации обновления.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень круто сделали! Было б еще круче если б было api13 а не 14

Comment: ааа... спасибо, понял!

Comment: @nesalexy Удалите, пожалуйста комментарии, они больше не соответствуют ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошая библиотека, вам поможет!
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1900

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Как минимум, слудет указать название библиотеки. Также можно привести примеры кода.